# How to get a list of functions what is available in a COM object?

Tags: object, com

I am looking for a program that generates/displays a list of which functions are available in a registered COM object. For example, if I select "excel-com," then it should display functions like open, save, close, insert.

How can this be done?

Comment: Use the SDK tool oleview.exe to view type libraries installed on your machine.

Comment: Not all COM objects are "discoverable". Some have a TypeLibrary aka TLB (embedded in the COM "server" .dll or as a standalone .tlb file that you can view using OleView). Some have an .idl and/or a .h (C/C++) in the Windows SDK. Some have nothing documented (more rare as you're not supposed to use them in that case).